# How to download Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, lts

Could you please help me download Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop.

I am new to this, and I really need help. I have a step by step guide I printed from the website, and on Step 4, it is asking me to to insert the DVD or the USB and reboot the machine.

Do I do that after I download the 18.04 LTS?
I will have to burn the download to the DVD first.
My main reason for downloading Ubuntu is to build a server and use Hyper-V to run.
Will there be a server that is already built that I can download?

Please help me realizing this.